# UART ESP and MEGA2560

Tags: serial

Could someone help me with some suggestions please?
Using ESP8266 and MEGA2560 on UART interface i want to display the message received on the mega serial to the LCD connected to it on i2c. The problem is that the LCD shows some strange unknown character and the serial monitor corresponding to mega shows this :

```
LED on LED OFF LED on LED OFF LED on LED OFF LED on LED OFF LED on LED OFF LED on LED OFF LED on LED OFF LED on LED OFF LED on LED OFF LED on
```

when it should display this:

```
LED on
LED OFF
LED on
LED OFF
LED on
LED OFF
LED on
LED OFF
LED on
LED OFF
LED on
LED OFF
LED on
LED OFF
LED on
LED OFF
LED on
LED OFF
```

the code for ESP is this:

```
int pinLed = 16;
void setup()
{

 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.begin(115200);
 pinMode(16,OUTPUT);
 delay(500);
}





void loop()
{

digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
Serial.print("LED on\n");
delay(5000);

digitalWrite(16,LOW);
Serial.print("LED OFF\n");
delay(5000);  

}
```

the code for mega is this:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F,20,4);

void setup() 
{

  Serial.begin(115200);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  while (!Serial)
  {

    Serial.print("Attempting to connect! ");
    Serial.print("Trying again...");
  }
}


  void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available()>0) 

  {
    char c = Serial.write(Serial.read());
    Serial.print(c);
    lcd.print(c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to your problems.

1. Use println instead of print.
2. Change `char c = Serial.write(Serial.read());` to `char c = Serial.read();`

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
println *emphasized text*
```

instead of

```
print *emphasized text*
```

Comment: use println instead print

Comment: why should they use println?